# How to get the action diagram when the group act on a set?

Tags: built-in-symbols, group-theory

I previously thought the orbital map would achieve this, but as the current answer or discuss in the comment. I realized that was wrong. And the Close behavior advice tells me "Needs details or clarity". So I re-edited the post.

---

As the textbook, when the $S_3$ can act on the root of $x^3-2$. The action diagram will be:

[image]

So Could we get the action diagram when the group act on a set by *MMA*?

---

## appendix

And there is [the second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0usD4.png), and the set about subgroups of $S_3$ is

```
S = {{Cycles[{}]}, {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}}], 
    Cycles[{{1, 3, 2}}]}, {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{1, 2}}]}, {Cycles[{}],
     Cycles[{{2, 3}}]}, {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{1, 3}}]}};
```

But I'm worried it will make this post chaos, so I offer it here as an appendix

Comment: I am also don't know the meaning,but `GroupOrbits[SymmetricGroup[3], {-0.63 - 1.1 I, 1.26, -0.63 + 1.1 I}, 
 Conjugate[#] &]` without error message.

Comment: perhaps `GroupOrbits[SymmetricGroup[3], {{-0.63 - 1.1 I, 1.26, -0.63 + 1.1 I}},
  Permute[Conjugate@#, #2] &]`?

Comment: `SymmetricGroup[3] // GroupElements` results in `{Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{2, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 2}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}}], 
 Cycles[{{1, 3, 2}}], Cycles[{{1, 3}}]}` so `{-0.63-1.1 I,1.26,-0.63+1.1 I}` is unclear to me.

Comment: Also I don't find the `Conjugate` option in the documentation to `GroupOrbits`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a separate answer looking at subgroups:

The roots and the rules to allow manipulation of permutations:

```
r = Power[2, 1/3] {1, Exp[2 Pi I/3], Exp[4 Pi I/3]} // ComplexExpand
rules = Thread[r -> Range[3]]
```

The subgroups generated be e,r,f, r f, r^2f:

```
sge = {{1, 2, 3}}
rg = {# &, Exp[2 Pi I/3] # &, Exp[4 Pi I/3] # &};
sgr = Union[(Table[rg[[j]] /@ r, {j, 3}] // ComplexExpand) /. rules]
fg = {# &, Conjugate@# &};
sf = Union[(Table[fg[[j]] /@ r, {j, 2}] // ComplexExpand) /. rules]
rfg = {# &, Composition[Exp[2 Pi I/3] # &, Conjugate[#] &], 
   Composition[Exp[2 Pi I/3] # &, Conjugate[#] &, Exp[2 Pi I/3] # &, 
    Conjugate[#] &]};
sgrf = Union[(Table[rfg[[j]] /@ r, {j, 2}] // ComplexExpand) /. rules]
r2f = {# &, Composition[Exp[4 Pi I/3] # &, Conjugate[#] &], 
   Composition[Exp[4 Pi I/3] # &, Conjugate[#] &, Exp[4 Pi I/3] # &, 
    Conjugate[#] &]};
sgr2f = Union[(Table[r2f[[j]] /@ r, {j, 3}] // ComplexExpand) /. 
   rules]
```

Converting subgroups to elements of $S_3$:

```
subgroups = 
Sort /@ Table[
PermutationCycles /@ j, {j, {sge, sgr, sf, sgrf, sgr2f}}]
```

Labeling the subgroups:

```
  sglab = Thread[
 subgroups -> {"<e>", "<r>",    "<f>", "<rf>", 
    "<\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)]\)f>"}]
```

Deriving relations between subgroups by conjugation:

```
s3 = GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[3]]
func[x_, y_] := PermutationProduct[x, #, InversePermutation[x]] & /@ y;
    res = TableForm[
  grp=Transpose[
   Map[Sort, (Table[Union@func[#, j] & /@ s3, {j, subgroups}]), {2}] /. 
    sglab], TableHeadings -> {Row[{"\[Tau](", #, ")"}] & /@ {"e", "f",
       "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)]\)f", "r", 
      "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)]\)", "rf"}, None}]
```

[image]

This is consistent with the hyperlinked relations.
The order is different but can  be re-ordered as desired

To produce the graph:

```
w = PermutationCycles /@ (grp[[{1, 2, 4}]] /. 
    Thread[{"<e>", "<r>", "<f>", "<rf>", 
       "<\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)]\)f>"} -> Range[5]])

gph = {Range[5], 
    DeleteCases[
     Union[Flatten@(Thread[
           DirectedEdge[Range[5], Permute[Range[5], #]]] & /@ 
         w[[2 ;; 3]])], DirectedEdge[a_, a_]]} /. 
   Thread[Range[5] -> {"<e>", "<r>", "<f>", "<rf>", 
      "<\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)]\)f>"}];
Graph[##, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   EdgeStyle -> {"<\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)]\)f>" \
\[DirectedEdge] "<rf>" -> Red, "<rf>" \[DirectedEdge] "<f>" -> Red, 
     "<f>" \[DirectedEdge] "<\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)]\)f>" ->
       Red}, EdgeLabels -> {"<\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)]\)f>" \
\[DirectedEdge] "<rf>" -> "r", "<rf>" \[DirectedEdge] "<f>" -> "r", 
     "<f>" \[DirectedEdge] "<\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)]\)f>" ->
       "r", "<rf>" \[DirectedEdge] 
       "<\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)]\)f>" -> "f"}] & @@ gph
```

[image]

Comment: What is your variable `grp`?

Comment: grp was the the t(e), t(r) and t(f). I apologise for omission and will correct when I get time. There other formatting errors I will correct. w just converts to cycles. I note that this shows <e> and <r> = A3 are normal subgroups of S3. Further, the chain <e> - <r>-S3 is such that S3/<r> is Abelian and <r>/<e> is Abelian. Hence S3 is a solvable group. I will correct my errors omission/ formatting when I have access to computer. It is 0100 in my Timezone.

Comment: I have made corrections.

Answer (score 5):

This is an extended comment. I post this for insight.  *r* and *f* generate the group. Note *r* is order 3 and *f* is order 2 and the group generated is of order 6 (in fact $S_3$). This is not unexpected as rotations (cyclically permute roots) and *f* (complex conjugation) is a transposition of roots. There 2 generators generate all the permutations of the roots.

```
    t = Composition @@@ 
   Tuples[{{# &, Exp[2 Pi I/3] # &, Exp[4 Pi I/3] # &}, {# &, 
      Conjugate[#] &}}];
r = Power[2, 1/3] {1, Exp[2 Pi I/3], Exp[4 Pi I/3]} // ComplexExpand
```

`t` are the group elements. `r` are the roots of $x^3-2$.

Group actions on roots:

```
a = Table[t[[j]] /@ r, {j, 6}] // ComplexExpand
```

Translating to permutations:

```
rules = Thread[r -> Range[3]];
p = a /. rules
```

yields: {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 3}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}

The cycles:

```
cyc = PermutationCycles /@ p
```

yields: {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{2, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 2}}],
Cycles[{{1, 3, 2}}], Cycles[{{1, 3}}]}

Note:

```
Sort@GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[3]] === Sort@cyc
```

yields `True` confirming the group generated by `r` and `f` is $S_3$

Note *r* and *f* do not commute. However, as expected yield same group:

```
u = Composition @@@ 
   Tuples[{{# &, Conjugate[#] &}, {# &, Exp[2 Pi I/3] # &, 
      Exp[4 Pi I/3] # &}}];
b = Table[t[[j]] /@ r, {j, 6}] // ComplexExpand;
q = b /. rules;
cycq = PermutationCycles /@ q
Sort[cycq] === Sort[GroupElements@SymmetricGroup[3]]
```

yields: `True`.

Answer (score 3):

I do not see why you would use the 3. parameter for the symmetric group S3.

Every group is isomorph to some permutation group. Therefore MMA deals with permutations of elements: 1,2,... You may always map the result back to the original group. By e.g.

```
rules=Thread[{1,2,3}->{-0.63 - 1.1 I, 1.26, -0.63 + 1.1 I}]
```

Now, e.g. the orbit of element 1 is:

```
GroupOrbits[SymmetricGroup[3], {1}]
(* {{1, 2, 3}} *)
```

Or with the original elements:

```
GroupOrbits[SymmetricGroup[3], {1}] /. rules
(* {{-0.63 - 1.1 I, 1.26, -0.63 + 1.1 I}} *)
```

Comment: Maybe you are right, but what I can't understand is that in your answer $r_1$,$r_2$ and $r_3$ are all equivalents, but in fact $r_2$ and $r_3$ have an additional relationship as [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Ada.png). If this relationship cannot be gotten with `GroupOrbits`, what function of mma would this require?

Comment: We are dealing here with  a group. That is a set and a 2-ary operation. In your case elements 1,2,3 and permutations. Your operation 2 <-> 3 is a permutation(Cycle[{{2,3}}] and is therefore already contained in the group S3.

Comment: Hi, I think the red arrow(from $r_2$ to $r_3$) is `permutation(Cycle[{{2,3}}]` as you said, but the blue arrow in [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Ada.png) is not. And this relationship(conjugacy) doesn't seem to manifest itself on the orbit.

Comment: No, you misinterprete "Cycle". Cycle[{{2,3}}] means the exchange of 2 and 3, that is it is the BLUE arrow. The red arrows are:  Cycle[{{1,2,3}}]

Comment: You are right. But if we just care about their orbit, then just the red arrow is enough, there is no need for that extra blue arrow. So the orbits don't seem to provide us with all the information. And I would like to use MMA to show all the relationships in the diagram, but I don't know what to do with it. The `GroupOrbits` used in my post don't look like they meet my requirements (after your analysis)

Comment: The orbit are the group elements into which a given element can be mapped by the group operation with all the elements in the group. In your case e.g. element 1 is mapped into elements 1,2,3 by the group operations (permutations). Therefore, the orbit contains elements 1,2,3. That is all. The orbit does not contain other relations like e.g. your arrows.

Comment: So is there any method that can get all relationships for these arrows by MMA? In fact, this is the core of my problem.

Comment: First, you must define what  a "relation" is. If you mean, which element is permuteted into which element, then the multiplication table contains all this information.

Comment: I have edited the post as the current information

Comment: Sorry to bother you one last time, but can `GroupOrbits` be used to draw a `CycleGraph` of a group to solve [my this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267486/how-to-draw-a-cycle-graph-of-a-group)? I don't know what mistake I have made in `GroupOrbits[g, GroupElements[g], PermutationProduct[#, #] &]`

Comment: `CycleGraph` gives you the subsets of points that are mapped into each other by the group operation. But not necessarily in the correct order.  To get this information you would need the multiplication table : mul. A column (or row) gives you all the elements into which some specific element is mapped by the group operation.

Comment: As your reminder, I have made one in following

Answer (score 0):

```
subgroups = Most[DeleteDuplicatesBy[
    PermutationGroup /@ Subsets[GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[3]]], GroupElements]];
gens = GroupGenerators[SymmetricGroup[3]];
RelationGraph[AnyTrue[Function[g, PermutationReplace[#, g]] /@ gens, 
   Function[e, (e == #2) && (#2 =!= #)]] &, subgroups]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
sortsols = Permute[sols, FindPermutation[{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}]];
Row[Show[
    ComplexListPlot[MapIndexed[Callout[#1, First[#2]] &, sortsols], 
     PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.05]], 
    GraphPlot[
     DirectedEdge @@@ Transpose[{Range[3], PermutationList[#, 3]}], 
     VertexCoordinates -> 
      MapIndexed[First[#2] -> # &, ReIm /@ sortsols], 
     EdgeStyle -> Red, SelfLoopStyle -> None], 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 150, PlotRange -> All] & /@
   GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[3]], Frame -> All]
```

[image]