# How to draw a cycle graph of a group?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, group-theory

*MMA* can plot a Cayley graph by `CayleyGraph` directly, which can help us to visualize the group:

```
CayleyGraph[AlternatingGroup[5], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

But sometimes a cycle graph is more intuitive in order to see the orbits. Here are some [ready-made cycle graphs](https://nathancarter.github.io/group-explorer/GroupExplorer.html), such as `AlternatingGroup[5]`:

[image]

`AbelianGroup[{4,4}]`:

[image]

How to draw a cycle graph of a group by *MMA*?

Comment: `FiniteGroupData[{"AlternatingGroup", 5}, "CycleGraph"]` and `FiniteGroupData[{"AbelianGroup", {4, 4}}, "CycleGraph"]` ?

Comment: @kglr Fun. Thanks very much. But how about group `PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 5, 4}}], Cycles[{{3, 4}}]}]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
groupCycleGraph[group_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Block[{cycles},
   cycles = 
    DeleteDuplicates[
     Function[{x}, 
       NestWhileList[PermutationProduct[#, x] &, 
        x, # != Cycles[{}] &]] /@ Rest[GroupElements@group], 
     SubsetQ[#1, #2] &];
   cycles = 
    Select[cycles, Count[cycles, x_ /; SubsetQ[x, #]] == 1 &];
   Graph[
    Flatten[(UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1, 1]) & /@ cycles], 
    opts]];

groupCycleGraph[
 PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 5, 4}}], Cycles[{{3, 4}}]}]]
```

[image]